# use project.identifier as variable in redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, redmine

In our redmine setup, corresponding to the project.identifier (not :project_id) we have folders in another server and the developers store the mysql database dumps related to their project. I am trying to write a plugin which just shows the list of all the database dumps.

For this initially I tried using net/ssh and then the plugin logs into the another server where the db dumps are located and does an ls. I show the ls output in an unordered list in the plugin's view. For this i should send the project.identifier as the argument to ls to get the list of dumps particular to that project. Could not figure out how to send local variables via Net::SSH.

Then I changed my idea of using net/ssh and now simply executing a  local script which does an ssh and ls. Now I want to use project.identifier again as an argument. How can i pass the value of project.identifier as an argument to the command in system call?

This is my controller.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

class BackupsController < ApplicationController
  helper :projects
  unloadable


  def index
  #host = '192.168.122.245'
  #user = 'root'
  #Net::SSH.start( host, user ) do |ssh|
  #@result = ssh.exec!('dumplist website')
  #end
  @identifier = "#{project.identifier}"
  @result = %x[dumpshow @identifier]
  end
end
```

dumpshow is my script which does an ssh runs `ls $1` . I want to send project.identifier as $1

With the above script I am getting the following error.
`NameError (undefined local variable or method 'project' for #<BackupsController:0x7ff5b4a756a0>):`

To summarize, I wanna use the variables from Redmine,'s core controller and model. This seems to be simple but I am missing it somewhere. Or there should be a very simple way of finding the current project's identifier as we find out the USer.Current.

Comment: To put it again in a simple way, How can I use the variables set in redmine's core controllers and models, in my custom plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. It was just params[:project_id]. Took time for me to get to the vocabulary of redmine. Has got limited dev documentation, i feel.